# OS X Webview is not displaying Flash video

Tags: macos, flash, webview, osx-mavericks

I have a simple Webview that opens `www.youtube.com`

The video portion of the site is black, but it can be clicked and it tells me that it's running Flash Player.

Do I need an additional setup for the webview in order to use the Flash plugin ?

The problem exists only on 10.9. Video is OK on 10.8

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem on Mavericks, but not sure this issue caused by Mavericks or the Flash player itself.

Comment: it's not working for me, even if I add the webview as a subview of NSTabView. Did you add any custom initialization code for the webview? Are you using OS X 10.9 as base SDK?

Comment: yep, if I disable browser plugins with `[[_webView preferences] setPlugInsEnabled:NO]` the HTML5 video loads properly, but fullscreen doesn't work. When I enable browser plugins it just displays a black box.

Answer (score 2):

Enabling `layerUsesCoreImageFilters` on the webView solves the problem on Mavericks:

`[self.webView setLayerUsesCoreImageFilters:YES];`

Related documentation in AppKit Release Notes for OS X v10.9: [Changes to layer rendering](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000741-CH2-SW49)